# How to create a dataframe from a model (Django)

Tags: django, pandas, dataframe, model, copy

I am developing an app in Django.
I have this model

```
class my_model(models.Model):  

    Field_A = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)        
    Field_B = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    Field_C = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to create a dataframe with columns names equal to model fields names,
containing in every row the model objects, and in every column the object fields values.

How can I do it? Is there a single command to do it? Or do I have to iterate?

EDIT: Here is the raw and unelegant solution that I found until now:

```
import pandas as pd

entries = my_model.objects.all()   

# this generates an array containing the names of the model fields
columns_names = [field.name for field in my_model._meta.get_fields()]

L_GI = len(entries)

    # generate empty dataframe
    GI = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns_names)

    for element in entries:       
        new_entry = {"Field_A":element.Field_A, "Field_B":element.Field_B, "Field_C":element.Field_C}
        GI = GI.append(new_entry, ignore_index=True)
```

I bet there is a faster way that avoids iteration. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question

I think you are forced to iterate them.

I have implemented it in 3 different ways so that you can choose your favorite one

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from django.core import serializers        

class PandasModelMixin(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    @classmethod
    def as_dataframe(cls, queryset=None, field_list=None):
        t1 = time.time()

        if queryset is None:
            queryset = cls.objects.all()
        if field_list is None:
            field_list = [_field.name for _field in cls._meta._get_fields(reverse=False)]

        data = []
        [data.append([obj.serializable_value(column) for column in field_list]) for obj in queryset]

        columns = field_list

        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
        print("Execution time without serialization: %s" % time.time()-t1)
        return df

    @classmethod
    def as_dataframe_using_django_serializer(cls, queryset=None):
        t1 = time.time()

        if queryset is None:
            queryset = cls.objects.all()

        if queryset.exists():
            serialized_models = serializers.serialize(format='python', queryset=queryset)
            serialized_objects = [s['fields'] for s in serialized_models]
            data = [x.values() for x in serialized_objects]

            columns = serialized_objects[0].keys()

            df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        print("Execution time using Django serializer: %s" % time.time()-t1)
        return df

    @classmethod
    def as_dataframe_using_drf_serializer(cls, queryset=None, drf_serializer=None, field_list=None):
        from rest_framework import serializers
        t1 = time.time()

        if queryset is None:
            queryset = cls.objects.all()

        if drf_serializer is None:
            class CustomModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
                class Meta:
                    model = cls
                    fields = field_list or '__all__'

            drf_serializer = CustomModelSerializer

        serialized_objects = drf_serializer(queryset, many=True).data
        data = [x.values() for x in serialized_objects]

        columns = drf_serializer().get_fields().keys()

        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
        print("Execution time using DjangoRestFramework serializer: %s" % time.time()-t1)
        return df
```

So inherit your Model in this way:

```
class MyModel(PandasModelMixin):  

    field_a = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)        
    field_b = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    field_c = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

and try the code in this way:

```
>> MyModel.as_dataframe() 

>> MyModel.as_dataframe_using_django_serializer() 

>> MyModel.as_dataframe_using_drf_serializer()
```

I have tried my code using a Model with 450 instances and 15 columns and I had these results:

> Execution time without serialization: 0.07040905952453613
>
> Execution time using Django serializer: 0.07644820213317871
>
> Execution time using DjangoRestFramework serializer: 0.12314629554748535

N.B.
I'm using Django 2.2 and Python 3.6.5